# VSCode: php-cs-fixer setRules not applied while setIndent is applied

Tags: visual-studio-code, php-cs-fixer

I'm using **VSCode** with **PHP CS Fixer** `v3.1.0`, but rules don't seem to be applied.

When I comment/uncomment `setIndent("\t")`, this setting is automatically applied and can be tested, but all rules in `setRules()` are not applied. For instance, arrays like `$myarray = array('foo', 'bar');` is not replaced by `$myarray = ['foo', 'bar'];` while I have the rule `array_syntax' => ['syntax' => 'short']`.

What's wrong with my configuration ?

`/Users/me/.vscode/.php-cs-fixer.php` :

```
<?php

return (new PhpCsFixer\Config())
    ->setRules([
        '@PSR2' => true,
        'array_indentation' => true,
        'array_syntax' => ['syntax' => 'short'],
        'combine_consecutive_unsets' => true,
        'class_attributes_separation' => ['elements' => ['method' => 'one',]],
        'multiline_whitespace_before_semicolons' => false,
        'single_quote' => true,

        'binary_operator_spaces' => [
            'operators' => [
                // '=>' => 'align',
                // '=' => 'align'
            ]
        ],
        // 'blank_line_after_opening_tag' => true,
        // 'blank_line_before_statement' => true,
        'braces' => [
            'allow_single_line_closure' => true,
        ],
        // 'cast_spaces' => true,
        // 'class_definition' => array('singleLine' => true),
        'concat_space' => ['spacing' => 'one'],
        'declare_equal_normalize' => true,
        'function_typehint_space' => true,
        'single_line_comment_style' => ['comment_types' => ['hash']],
        'include' => true,
        'lowercase_cast' => true,
        // 'native_function_casing' => true,
        // 'new_with_braces' => true,
        // 'no_blank_lines_after_class_opening' => true,
        // 'no_blank_lines_after_phpdoc' => true,
        'no_blank_lines_before_namespace' => true,
        // 'no_empty_comment' => true,
        // 'no_empty_phpdoc' => true,
        // 'no_empty_statement' => true,
        'no_extra_blank_lines' => [
            'tokens' => [
                'curly_brace_block',
                'extra',
                // 'parenthesis_brace_block',
                // 'square_brace_block',
                'throw',
                'use',
            ]
        ],
        // 'no_leading_import_slash' => true,
        // 'no_leading_namespace_whitespace' => true,
        // 'no_mixed_echo_print' => array('use' => 'echo'),
        'no_multiline_whitespace_around_double_arrow' => true,
        // 'no_short_bool_cast' => true,
        // 'no_singleline_whitespace_before_semicolons' => true,
        'no_spaces_around_offset' => true,
        // 'no_trailing_comma_in_list_call' => true,
        // 'no_trailing_comma_in_singleline_array' => true,
        // 'no_unneeded_control_parentheses' => true,
        // 'no_unused_imports' => true,
        'no_whitespace_before_comma_in_array' => true,
        'no_whitespace_in_blank_line' => true,
        // 'normalize_index_brace' => true,
        'object_operator_without_whitespace' => true,
        // 'php_unit_fqcn_annotation' => true,
        // 'phpdoc_align' => true,
        // 'phpdoc_annotation_without_dot' => true,
        // 'phpdoc_indent' => true,
        // 'phpdoc_inline_tag' => true,
        // 'phpdoc_no_access' => true,
        // 'phpdoc_no_alias_tag' => true,
        // 'phpdoc_no_empty_return' => true,
        // 'phpdoc_no_package' => true,
        // 'phpdoc_no_useless_inheritdoc' => true,
        // 'phpdoc_return_self_reference' => true,
        // 'phpdoc_scalar' => true,
        // 'phpdoc_separation' => true,
        // 'phpdoc_single_line_var_spacing' => true,
        // 'phpdoc_summary' => true,
        // 'phpdoc_to_comment' => true,
        // 'phpdoc_trim' => true,
        // 'phpdoc_types' => true,
        // 'phpdoc_var_without_name' => true,
        // 'increment_style' => true,
        // 'return_type_declaration' => true,
        // 'self_accessor' => true,
        // 'short_scalar_cast' => true,
        // 'single_blank_line_before_namespace' => true,
        // 'single_class_element_per_statement' => true,
        // 'space_after_semicolon' => true,
        // 'standardize_not_equals' => true,
        'ternary_operator_spaces' => true,
        // 'trailing_comma_in_multiline_array' => true,
        'trim_array_spaces' => true,
        'unary_operator_spaces' => true,
        'whitespace_after_comma_in_array' => true,
        'space_after_semicolon' => true,
        // 'single_blank_line_at_eof' => false
    ])
    // ->setIndent("\t")
    ->setLineEnding("\n")
;
```

**VSCode** settings regarding **PHP CS Fixer**:

```
{
  ...
  "php-cs-fixer.executablePath": "php-cs-fixer",
  "php-cs-fixer.onsave": true,
  "php-cs-fixer.rules": "@PSR2",
  "php-cs-fixer.config": ".php-cs-fixer.php;.php-cs-fixer.dist.php;.php_cs;.php_cs.dist",
  "php-cs-fixer.allowRisky": false,
  "php-cs-fixer.pathMode": "override",
  "php-cs-fixer.exclude": [],
  "php-cs-fixer.autoFixByBracket": true,
  "php-cs-fixer.autoFixBySemicolon": false,
  "php-cs-fixer.formatHtml": false,
  "php-cs-fixer.documentFormattingProvider": true,
  ...
}
```

I'm using **VSCode** extension [vscode-php-cs-fixer](https://github.com/junstyle/vscode-php-cs-fixer).

Comment: Seem correct to me. Have you tested setting `"php-cs-fixer.config": "php-cs-fixer.php",` in `settings.json`? and/or moving the config file to the workspace root?

Answer (score 0):

[This tutorial](https://medium.com/@armorasha/php-cs-fixer-how-to-install-vs-code-2020-windows-10-75b6d5ed03ce) will be helpful for you to config php-cs-fixer properly in VSCode

Also I will share below my configurations in settings.json file of VSCode that is relevant to php-cs-fixer extension.

```
// Add following php cs fixer settings to your VSCode's existing settings.json file
"php.suggest.basic": true,
"[php]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": false,
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "junstyle.php-cs-fixer",
},
"php-cs-fixer.executablePath": "${extensionPath}\\php-cs-fixer.phar",
"php-cs-fixer.executablePathWindows": "${extensionPath}\\php-cs-fixer.phar",
"php-cs-fixer.rules": "@PSR2",
"php-cs-fixer.config": "C:\\Users\\your_user_name\\AppData\\Roaming\\Composer\\vendor\\bin\\config.php_cs",
"php-cs-fixer.allowRisky": false, //it is safe not to allow risky linting
"php-cs-fixer.pathMode": "override",
"php-cs-fixer.exclude": [],
"php-cs-fixer.autoFixByBracket": true,
"php-cs-fixer.autoFixBySemicolon": false,
"php-cs-fixer.documentFormattingProvider": true,
"php.validate.executablePath": "",
```

Also make sure you follow the above tutorial properly and download the "config.php_cs" file from the tutorial and move it to the path defined in "`php-cs-fixer.config`" of above code. Also be sure to replace "your_user_name" in the path of the above code to your PC's actual username. Then you can add a long array and try formatting it to a short array. Your configuration file seems okay to me.